# Sql-injection error

Tags: sql-injection

I am trying to do SQL-injection attack on a local website on my localhost. I am trying to get all the products from product table using the wildcard *';--* but there seems to be some problem with the query. It's giving me this error

> 'Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\tplus\products.php on
>   line 151'

Here is my  PHP code

```
 <?php 

//$search_value = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['search']);

$search_value = $_GET['search'];

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM products where p_name LIKE '%".$search_value."%'");
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {


                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>";
                            echo $row['p_name']; 
                        echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>";
                            echo $row['p_price']; 
                        echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>";
                            echo $row['p_brand']; 
                        echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>";
                            echo $row['p_info']; 
                        echo "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";

 }

  ?>
```

Comment: Technically, the message has 'warning', and not 'error'. That message means that the `$result` parameter was a boolean and not a result set, because the query failed for some reason. See the php.net documentation examples on how to check for the query return value.

Answer (score 0):

`Try this
if (!$result) {
   die(echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error())
}`

Comment: error checks are done in a separate file, there is no problem with connection

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if

```
"SELECT * FROM products where p_name LIKE '%".$search_value."%'"
```

is a valid SQL statement.

The indication is that it is not - hence the error.

Perhaps output that string and check where the SQL statement is incorrect.

Comment: PS: As you are a bit relax about error checking - Are you sure that you are connected to the database?

Comment: I am not relaxed. I am connected to the database, doing the connection in a separate file

Comment: You are relaxed about checking for errors - hence not checking the return value `$result`. Have you checked that the return value when making the connection

Comment: The query is working absolutely fine. my question is regarding injection attacks. I am doing an attack on my own local website.

Comment: The query is NOT working - that is why you `$result` set to false. If the query is working it would be returning a `mysqli_result` object - please read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Let me clarify here when I type some word(ODI KIT) in the search bar, the query gives the result(all the ODI KIT products) as expected but when I type in ';-- for the injection attack, it gives the above error

Comment: .. Is that expected? I think so

Comment: Try entering in "';drop table products;" as a query

Comment: And what happened to the table `products`?

Comment: It isn't being dropped. My query might be wrong, but I am not understanding this